# Angular 9 - Convoluted child/parent navigation

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing, angular-router, angular9

I've just completely stuck with the following.
I have some set of routes with two different parent layouts.

**routing.module.ts**

```
{
    path: '',
    component: FrameworkComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'products',
        component: ProductListingPageComponent,
        canActivate: [EnsureAuthenticated]
      },
      {
        path: 'categories',
        component: CategoryListingPageComponent,
        canActivate: [EnsureAuthenticated]
      }
    ]
},
{
    path: '',
    component: AppComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginPageComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'register',
        component: RegistrationPageComponent
      }
    ]
}
```

So being on LoginPageComponents I just would like to navigate to `/products` path (in case of success during logging in)

**login-page.component.ts**

```
this.authService.logIn(this.credentials)
    .then(_ => this.router.navigateByUrl('/products'))
    .catch(this.handleLoginError.bind(this));
```

As a result I get nothing. Just a request flies to a server and I see successful login and nothing more - no errors etc.

Could you please advise?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking the response that you're getting?

```
this.authService.logIn(this.credentials)
    .then(res => {
     console.log(res);
     this.router.navigateByUrl('/products');
    }).catch(this.handleLoginError.bind(this));
```

Comment: I have, I receive my JWT token there so that I know authentication is successful.

Comment: Oh ok, just wanted to make sure. However I think the problem is in the routing path. Could you make a stackblitz?

Comment: Well, I've created some blitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gj1nqt a bit simplified (w/o a Promise). There on blitz it works fine... Seems that the root cause somewhere in promises.

Answer (score 0):

After thousands of trial and errors I've found the solution. An issue was in `canActivate` property. It checks whether login token is in place and I had forgotten to set this token during login previously.